# Soundmanager 2 events won't fire/trigger

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

The soundmanager 2 events won't fire. Here is a snippet where the console.logs don't fire at all, therefore any of the different events aren't being triggered when they should.

```
soundManager.setup({
    url: "js/swf/",
    preferFlash: false,
    useFlashBlock: false,
    onready: function() {

        soundManager.play(url, id, {
            id: id,
            url: url,

            onplay: function() {    
                console.log("test");        
            },
            onresume: function() {
                console.log("test");
            },
            onpause: function() {
                console.log("test");
            },
            onfinish: function() {
                console.log("test");
                next();
            },
            whileplaying: function() {
                console.log("test");
            },      
        }); 

    },

    defaultOptions: {
        multiShotEvents: true, // allow events (onfinish()) to fire for each shot, if supported.
    }

});
```

Is this because I have flash disabled? There is a bug currently where flash doesan't work in chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tested it in other browser other than Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the

```
var sound = soundManager.createSound({id: 'soundId', url: '1.mp3'});
sound.play({
    onplay: function() {
        ...
    }
})
```

you missed "createSound"

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250573/why-does-soundmanager-2-not-fire-onload-event-in-firefox-23

Does it mean there is no way to declare the callback for an event in soundManager.setup?